# Having a issue in Local host

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

try to do with react and local host but it is showing direct file not website. please help me out. I am stuck from last 3-4 hours still can't find the solution. waiting for you guy's to help me out with this problem.

Comment: Did you run `npm start`?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Of course, since you don't describe here how you're trying to host your website, I can only speculate.

If you are using a web server, such as Apache, then you need to point the [document root](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/core.html#documentroot) to the public folder.

this is of course also true for all other webservers you might use.

However, from your picture it looks like you are trying to host a development version. Keep in mind, before you use an app productively, you should create an appropriate [build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/).

You can do this with

```bash
npm run build
```

If you really want to host your development version on the server, you will of course have to start this server with `npm start` accordingly

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to run `liveserver` in `VS code` or similar. Live server does not build your code. It just serves things as they are. You can use live server after building your project or for rendering html files.

For running the React project, you need to run `npm run start` or `npm run dev` or similar command. You can find that out in your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

For react, you'll have to run a npm script (which are given in your package.json file) to host it on your localhost, which usually is

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: I forgot to mention you have to type this script in your terminal. And keep your project directory opened in the terminal when you run this script